# Exporting plaintext for excel with sympy

Tags: python, excel, sympy

Most of my schoolwork for numerical analysis is done in `excel`, so I use excel functions extensively. However, I would like to start incorporating `sympy` into my workflow.

My question is is there a way to print functions from `sympy` to make them copy-paste-able to `excel`? What I end up doing when I get my output in `sympy` is reformatting it for `excel` i.e., regroup some terms so they are clearer to excel, and more often, change `**` to `^`.

I am aware that I can simply use `mathematica` for this, which prints my output to plaintext (where exponents are by default expressed with `^`), but I am wondering if I can do the same with `sympy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If mathematica style output is sufficient then the following should do:

```
import sympy
from sympy.printing import mathematica_code

x = sympy.symbols('x')
sympy.printing.mathematica_code(sympy.integrate(x**2,x))
```

Documentation [here](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/printing.html).

There are lots of other printing options which might work even better than mathematica style output.

Comment: This has been most useful. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad it works for you. Now it would be great for other users (and me) if you accepted the answer as solution to your problem. You could also leave a comment if you did end up using something else than `mathematica` output.